# Circle centre point from two angles and circle overal

Tags: circles, tangent-line

There are two overlapping circles. Point A is known (it lies on the y axis) and the y value is given. This point makes a tangent to a circle with an unknown centre point and radius (centre C on the diagram)[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkef.png). A tangent angle at an overlap is known at point B and diameter is specified for this circle.

From this how can you calculate the Centre point and radius of the unknown circle?

[image]
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkef.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two reference circles are a distraction. You have two points $A$ and $B$ on the unknown circle and the directions (after a little bit of computation) of the tangents to the unknown circle at those two points. Its center $C$ is at the intersection of the perpendiculars to those two tangent lines at the two points of tangency.

The slope of the tangent to either of the reference circles at the point $(x,y)$ is simply $-x/y$, and you can then find the slope of the tangent to the unknown circle via the formula for the tangent of a sum.